# Handling the focusing click using Raw Input

Tags: c++, winapi, raw-input

I wish to handle mouse clicks in my game with the Raw Input API using the WM_INPUT messages.
I'm only interested in the mouse clicks while my app is active.

**When the window is inactive and I click into the window putting it in focus no WM_INPUT message is generated for that click.** I can handle every other click except the one that brings my window to focus.

With the RIDEV_INPUTSINK flag I can catch that one missing event but then I would have to somehow ignore every other message that I get while my app is inactive.

Most apps and windowed programs process the "activating click" just like a normal one, they don't ignore it. They probably use the "legacy" messages, as they arrive correctly.

Should I mix raw input with the legacy mouse handling? Should I use INPUTSINK flag and ignore messages selectively? If so, how?

Since Microsoft recommends raw input for games, I hope there is a common solution to this problem that I just couldn't find so far.

Relevant snippet from code:

Registering the raw input device

```
RAWINPUTDEVICE Rid[1];    
Rid[0].usUsagePage = 0x01;
Rid[0].usUsage = 0x02;
Rid[0].dwFlags = 0;   // adds HID mouse
Rid[0].hwndTarget = 0;

RegisterRawInputDevices(Rid, 1, sizeof(Rid[0]))
```

For convenience here's a full sample program that showcases my problem.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <strsafe.h>

const char g_szClassName[] = "myWindowClass";

// Step 4: the Window Procedure
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
        case WM_CLOSE:
            DestroyWindow(hwnd);
            break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        case WM_INPUT:
        {
            UINT dwSize;

            GetRawInputData((HRAWINPUT)lParam, RID_INPUT, NULL, &dwSize,
                sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER));
            LPBYTE lpb = new BYTE[dwSize];
            if (lpb == NULL)
            {
                return 0;
            }

            if (GetRawInputData((HRAWINPUT)lParam, RID_INPUT, lpb, &dwSize,
                sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER)) != dwSize)
                OutputDebugString(TEXT("GetRawInputData does not return correct size !\n"));

            RAWINPUT* raw = (RAWINPUT*)lpb;

            size_t const cchDest = 1000;
            TCHAR pszDest[cchDest];

            if (raw->header.dwType == RIM_TYPEMOUSE && raw->data.mouse.ulButtons)
            {
                auto hResult = StringCchPrintf(pszDest, STRSAFE_MAX_CCH, TEXT("Mouse: usFlags=%04x ulButtons=%04x usButtonFlags=%04x usButtonData=%04x ulRawButtons=%04x lLastX=%04x lLastY=%04x ulExtraInformation=%04x\r\n"),
                    raw->data.mouse.usFlags,
                    raw->data.mouse.ulButtons,
                    raw->data.mouse.usButtonFlags,
                    raw->data.mouse.usButtonData,
                    raw->data.mouse.ulRawButtons,
                    raw->data.mouse.lLastX,
                    raw->data.mouse.lLastY,
                    raw->data.mouse.ulExtraInformation);

                if (FAILED(hResult))
                {
                    // TODO: write error handler
                }
                OutputDebugString(pszDest);
            }

            delete[] lpb;
        }
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG Msg;

    //Step 1: Registering the Window Class
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = 0;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = g_szClassName;
    wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Window Registration Failed!", "Error!",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    // Step 2: Creating the Window
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
        g_szClassName,
        "The title of my window",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 240, 120,
        NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    if (hwnd == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Window Creation Failed!", "Error!",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    RAWINPUTDEVICE Rid[1];

    Rid[0].usUsagePage = 0x01;
    Rid[0].usUsage = 0x02;
    Rid[0].dwFlags = 0;   // adds HID mouse
    Rid[0].hwndTarget = 0;

    if (RegisterRawInputDevices(Rid, 1, sizeof(Rid[0])) == FALSE) {
        //registration failed. Call GetLastError for the cause of the error
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    // Step 3: The Message Loop
    while (GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    }
    return Msg.wParam;
}
```

**UPDATE**

For now I found a workaround by mixing legacy and raw input. In the WM_ACTIVATE message I check if the wParam is 2. If so it means that the window was activated using a mouse click.

In this case I actually process the next WM_LBUTTONDOWN, but only one time (and the other buttons as well).

This is a terrible hack so I'm still looking for a proper solution.

Comment: Interesting.  There are professional applications that show this issue. I have to click twice, once to get focus, the other to move the mouse.  If you find out how to do this, you may want to post it publicly. Or maybe submit as a bug to Microsoft.

Comment: @Áron Ürögdi I can't reproduce this issue when debugging on Windows 10 with version 16299, it does generate WM_INPUT message when I click the inactive window. So which OS version do you use?

Comment: Are you sure you're getting the button down event as well? And not only the button up? I'll get back to you with the exact version but I've seen this on many different computers.

Comment: By the way my Windows version is this:
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.471]

Comment: @ÁronÜrögdi I can get WM_INPUT message on both 16299,17134.1 and 17763.134. But it is weird that `raw->data.mouse.ulButtons` is always zero. If you have 17134.1 or 17763 you can test to see if it can reproduce this issue.